# My character going left but not going right (CONSOLE GAME)

Tags: c++

I working on my project this project have a frame to [100] x [25] matrix and i try to add animation but my character is going left but it's not going right.

i tried with "counter" variable but its not work.

```
int counter = 1;
int counter2 = 1;
int left_border = 1;
int matris1 = sizeof(map)/100;
int matris2 = sizeof(map[0])/4;
int startx = 19;
int starty = 8;


while (true)
...
int right = 0, left = 0;
...

for (int a = 0; a < matris2; a++)
     cout << "\n#"; //i have this because i make it square map. 
     for (int k = 0; k < matris1 - 2; k++)
      {
            if (left == 1)
            {
                if (((startx+2)-counter) == left_border)
                {
                    counter = 0;
                    //cout << "SINIR!!"<< endl ;
                }
                if (k == (startx-counter) and a == starty)
                {
                    counter += 1;
                    cout << "O";
                }
                else {
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            else if (right == 1)
                {
                    if (k == (startx+counter2) and a == starty)
                    {
                        counter2 += 1;
                        cout << "O";
                    }
```

its need to be going right but its not.
if you need full code.
https://codeshare.io/UbKVU

[![This is the map and "O" is the character]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyGQo.png

Comment: Have you tried running your code through a debugger?  You should identify the problematic code and post the minimal code required to reproduce the problem.  See [mre].

Comment: You should really avoid non-english names for variables, because they're gibberish for most people here reading that code.

Comment: Offtopic: Standard output is not best choice for this kind console game. Standard C++ do not have anything for such case. I recommend use of `ncurses` library.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz you so right i updated.

Comment: If your console supports, you might try with [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_output_sequences) to move cursor to desired location and then overwrite previous output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is very difficult to follow - you should have a coordinate system. I've made a simple example below. Update the player coordinate when a key is pressed and redraw the map x by y position, if the player is there then draw the 'O', otherwise if its a wall draw an 'X' (in this case), otherwise draw a space ' '.

```
using namespace std; 
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAPW 15 // map width
#define MAPH 15 // map height

int map[MAPW][MAPH];

#define WALL 1
#define EMPTY 0

void initmap()
{
    // just set the map to have walls around the border
    for (int x = 0; x < MAPW; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < MAPH; y++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == (MAPW - 1) || y == (MAPH - 1))
                map[x][y] = WALL;
            else
                map[x][y] = EMPTY;
        }
    }   
}

int px = MAPW / 2; // player x
int py = MAPH / 2; // player y

void main()
{
    initmap(); // initialize map
    cout << "Press A/W/S/D to begin and move";
    while (1)
    {
        if (kbhit()) // key pressed?
        {
            switch (getch()) // which key?
            {
            case 'a':
                if (px > 0 && map[px - 1][py] != WALL) // can go left? 
                    px--; // update x coordinate

                break;
            case 'd':
                if (px < (MAPW-1) && map[px + 1][py] != WALL) // can go right?
                    px++; // update x coordinate

                break;
            case 'w':

                if (py > 0 && map[px][py - 1] != WALL) // can go up?
                    py--; // update y coordinate

                break;
            case 's':
                if (py < MAPH && map[px][py + 1] != WALL) // can go down?
                    py++; // update y coordinate
                break;
            }

            // update map - clear screen and redraw
            system("CLS");

            // draw map each line
            for (int y = 0; y < MAPH; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < MAPW; x++)
                {
                    // its a wall?
                    if (map[x][y] == WALL)
                        cout << "X";
                    else
                    {
                        // is the player there?
                        if (x == px && y == py)
                        {
                            // draw the player
                            cout << "O";
                        }
                        else // empty space
                            cout << " ";

                    }
                }
                // next line
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```